Is it possible to close WebView from flutter web site opened by webview?
I deploy web site for example www.abc.com made by flutter web, let's say this is Flutter Project B.
And I show this flutter web page from flutter app proejct Flutter Project A.
in Flutter A:
InAppWebView(
                    key: webViewKey,
                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                      url:
                          WebUri("www.abc.com"),
                    ),
                    initialSettings: settings,
                    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                      webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    onPermissionRequest: (controller, permissionRequest) async {
                      return PermissionResponse(
                        resources: permissionRequest.resources,
                        action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT,
                      );
                    },
                    shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                        (controller, navigationAction) async {
                      var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                      if (![
                        "http",
                        "https",
                        "file",
                        "chrome",
                        "data",
                        "javascript",
                        "about"
                      ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                        if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
                          await launchUrl(
                            uri,
                          );
                          return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                        }
                      }
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                    },
                    onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                      });
                      controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                        handlerName: "backButtonPressed",
                        callback: (arguments) {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {},
                    onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                      if (progress == 100) {}
                      setState(() {
                        this.progress = progress / 100;
                      });
                    },
                    onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.url = url.toString();
                      });
                    },
                  ),

And Project B looks like below screen.

So If I press this back button I want to close WebView which is ProjectB.
But the problem is WebView is created in ProjectA.
Is it possible to close WebView from ProjectB?

are you saying ProjectB also has a webview?
